# Wrong date in HttpCookie sending to browser

Tags: c#, session-cookies, forms-authentication, utc, httpcookie

I am having a problem while sending a HttpCookie expiration to the browser, I am setting it with DateTime.Now but in various browsers a different value is appearing.

Here is the code and what appears in the browser.

PS: I have tested the following browsers (Chrome, Firefox and Edge) and the same problem occurs.

```
var expiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, usr.Id.ToString(), DateTime.Today, expiration, true, string.Empty);
string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket)
{
   Secure = Request.RequireSSL(),
   Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath,
   Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain,
   Expires = authTicket.Expiration
 };

 Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

[Cookie in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xgsB.png)

[Debugging the expiration time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V3Vu.png)

Comment: `DateTime.UtcNow`?

Comment: Does `expiration` match `authTicket.Expiration`?

Comment: What is the time difference?  What timezone are you in?

Comment: My timezone is Brazilian, I already tried it with UtcNow and it did not work. The difference is around 10 hours more than what I wanted.

Comment: @DanWilson yes, i set the authTicket.Expiration in create of FormsAuthenticationTicket

Comment: @Neil in the example, the time to expiration is 17/10/2018 10:58:18, that is, the DateTime.Now at that moment it was 17/10/2018 10:28:18 and in browser appears the time that is in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please observe your code below:

```
var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, usr.Id.ToString(), DateTime.Today, expiration, true, string.Empty);
```

On third parameter you are using `DateTime.Today` and the rigth way is to use `DateTime.Now`.

This should be the right code:

```
var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, usr.Id.ToString(), DateTime.Now, expiration, true, string.Empty);
```

Please let me know if it works for you.
Regards.